# Updates for Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, upgrade, updates, ppa

I recently upgraded  Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS after but after noticing degraded performance and several bugs in 12.04. I downgraded back to 11.10 which now zips along quite fine as before, on my machine.

However what I would like clarified is that after support for 11.10 is stopped in April, if I decide to do a clean install of 11.10 on a machine, will the update manager still offer to install the (*last*) updates and security fixes that were made for 11.10 or will it simply offer to upgrade to 12.04 LTS.

If I add other ppa's such as google google chrome and spotify etc. will/can they still offer upgrades for their software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have noticed degraded performance because you were upgrading the system from one distribution to another (ie; from 11.10 to 12.04). It happens at times. I would suggest you to do a clean installation of 12.04. Or if you wish to wait for a month, do a clean install of upcoming release 13.04.

But please we aware that starting from 13.04, interim releases would be supported for 9 months instead of the usual 18 months. LTS releases would continue to be supported for 3/5 years as the case may be.

If you wish to continue using 11.10 (not recommended), Canonical won't publish any further security/bug-fix updates. However, you would be able to download the ones already released. You would also be able to install other softwares for your distribution. For this you would have to make certain changes to `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Follow the instructions in this question:

- [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

As far as PPAs are concerned, it really depends on the PPA maintainer (Google/Spotify) if they wish to maintain compatibility with EOL Distribution Releases. So, there's no guarantee that they would continue to provide further updates for 11.10 users.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, that confirms things for me. To clarify I did do a clean install of 12.04 from DVD not an upgrade. and the downgrade was a clean install as well as upon research I see a lot of people have problem with the upgrade route. I think my problems may lie with the fact that I'm still using AWN and maybe emerald window manager too...but I really do prefer them to Unity and Ubuntu's dark themes..